# Non pickleable Parallel joblib

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a zip file with many .dat files. In each of them, I am aiming to apply some function that outputs two results, and I want to save the result of that function and the time that takes into three lists. The order matters. Here is the code to do it with no parallel computing:

```
result_1 = []
result_2 = []
runtimes = []
args_function = 'some args' # Always the same

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "r") as zip_ref:
    for name in sorted(zip_ref.namelist()):
        data = np.loadtxt(zip_ref.open(name))
        start_time = time.time()
        a, b = function(data, args_function)
        runtimes.append(time.time() - start_time)

result_1.append(a)
result_2.append(b)
```

This seems to me embarrassingly parallel, so I did:

```
result_1 = []
result_2 = []
runtimes = []
args_function = 'some args' # Always the same

def compute_paralel(name, zip_ref):
    data = np.loadtxt(zip_ref.open(name))
    start_time = time.time()
    a, b = function(data, args_function)
    runtimes.append(time.time() - start_time)

    result_1.append(a)
    result_2.append(b)

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "r") as zip_ref:
     Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(compute_paralel)(name, zip_ref) for name in sorted(zip_ref.namelist()))
```

But rises me the following error: `pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.`. Therefore I'm not really sure what to do... Any ideas?

Comment: What function `Parallel` are you using? That isn't part of the standard `multiprocessing` library.

Comment: What happens if you close the ZipFile before running the parallel task? I assume it doesn't like pickling the open context manager.

Comment: When you spawn processes with `multiprocessing` data to another process is transferred through pickling and unpickling. Not every data type can be pickled. `PicklingError` says that you try to pickle (transfer to another process) data that can't be pickled. I guess it is something returned by `delayed(...)(...)`.